# How to make ajaxfileupload work with dynamically generated file inputs

Tags: jquery, asp.net, upload

I need to use this [plugin](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) for my project, but it only seems to work properly when the file input is put in the raw code.However, when I try to call it from the file inputs that were dynamically generated, `context.Request.Files.Count` always returns 0.

## This is the [article](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/async-file-upload-jquery-and) I used as a guide:

And this is how I tried to adapt that article to my needs:

**ASPX and jQuery:**

```
<%@ Page Title="Página principal" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ajaxfileupload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnGenerateFileInputs").click(function () {
                var body = $("#tbDatos > tbody");
                for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    var row = $("<tr>");
                    var col = $("<td>");
                    col.append(
                    "<div><input id='fupFile_" + i + "' type='file' accept='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.SpreadsheetML.Sheet'/>" +
                    "<input id='btnUpload_" + i + "' type='button' value='Upload' />" +
                    "</div>"
                    );
                    row.append(col);
                    body.append(row);
                    add_clickUploadFile("btnUpload_" + i);
                }
            });
            function add_clickUploadFile(elemId) {
                elem = $("#" + elemId);         
                elem.on('click', function () {
                    var idFileUpload = $(this).prev().attr("id");
                    $.ajaxFileUpload({
                        url: 'AjaxFileUploader.ashx',
                        secureuri: false,
                        fileElementId: idFileUpload,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data, status) {
                            if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {
                                if (data.error != '') {
                                    alert(data.error);
                                } else {
                                    alert(data.msg);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (data, status, e) {
                            alert(e);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;                    
                });
            }            
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <input id="btnGenerateFileInputs" type="button" value="Generate File Inputs" />
    <table id="tbDatos" style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

**Handler:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

namespace jQueryFileUpload
{
    
    public class AjaxFileuploader : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                string path = context.Server.MapPath("~/Temp");
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

                var file = context.Request.Files[0];

                string fileName;

                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE")
                {
                    string[] files = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                    fileName = files[files.Length - 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    fileName = file.FileName;
                }
                string strFileName = fileName;
                fileName = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
                file.SaveAs(fileName);


                string msg = "{";
                msg += string.Format("error:'{0}',\n", string.Empty);
                msg += string.Format("msg:'{0}'\n", strFileName);
                msg += "}";
                context.Response.Write(msg);


            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main difference between the example in the article and the code I posted above is the following :

Instead of calling the JavaScript function directly when the button is created I decided to do this:

[image]

And then when the button is clicked, call the handler, passing the id of the current file input.

[image]

As I told you earlier, the handler is invoked, but the `context.Request.Files.Count` always returns 0, as if no file was selected.

Any ideas why this could be happening??

As always any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On difference that I can see in your code and article's code is that your input fields lack "name" attribute. So try changing the following code:

```
col.append(
    "<div><input id='fupFile_" + i + "' type='file' accept='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.SpreadsheetML.Sheet'/>" +
    "<input id='btnUpload_" + i + "' type='button' value='Upload' />" +
    "</div>"
  );
```

to

```
col.append(
    "<div><input id='fupFile_" + i + "' name='fupFile_" + i + "' type='file' accept='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.SpreadsheetML.Sheet'/>" +
    "<input id='btnUpload_" + i + "' name='btnUpload_" + i + "' type='button' value='Upload' />" +
    "</div>"
  );
```